# submitting a form with a dynamic form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had few form fields which are generated dynamically values

and i am sing jquery submit to submit the form, want to do as the way it is happening

```
function x() {
document.getElementById('myform').submit()
}
```

does it workds, send the form to the server page but i am trying to create one variable and assign all the dynamic form fields values to that variables and pass that instead to the submit

like this as example

```
var singlefeld = $('input[class="boxes"]').is(":checked").map(function () {
                return this.value;
              }).get();
```

and send `singlefield` instead to the submit as a list

Comment: Include a hidden field in the form and assign `singlefield` as its value before form submission. Or use AJAX. Also note that `is()` won't work for you. Use this instead: `$('input[class="boxes"]:checked").map(function() { ...`

Comment: You're pretty much there. Have something like this <input id="single" name="single" /> and when you are doing combining things into singlefield, do $('#single').val(singlefield) before your submit. Rory ( love that name - 'red' in gaelic) said it better, I'd say.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour